# How to set the funcion timeout for Genetic Algorithm to more than 10 sec?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, timeout, genetic-algorithm

I have a loss function that opens an external *.exe* file for calculation, and running this executable file usually takes around 2 or 3 minutes. It works very well, but When I want to pass this function to the Genetic Algorithm for optimization, I face this error:

```
AssertionError: After 10.0 seconds delay func_timeout: the given function 
does not provide any output.
```

So it obviously says that GA waited 10 sec and did not receive anything so bye-bye... Since the function needs more time to return the result (loss), it will not continue.

Is there any way to set `time_out` to more than 10.0 sec? I couldn't find the option in algorithm_param or ga_model itself. These are my parameters:

```
from geneticalgorithm import geneticalgorithm as ga

algorithm_param = {'max_num_iteration': None,\
               'population_size':100,\
               'mutation_probability':0.1,\
               'elit_ratio': 0.01,\
               'crossover_probability': 0.5,\
               'parents_portion': 0.3,\
               'crossover_type':'uniform',\
               'max_iteration_without_improv':None}

ga_model = ga(function=loss_fn,
          dimension=(2),
          variable_type='real',
          variable_boundaries=varbound,
          algorithm_parameters=algorithm_param)

ga_model.run()
```

I searched here and other forums, but almost all the related questions are for actually limiting a function to a particular time (manually setting a time out for a process), not the opposite thing; I want to remove the restriction.

Comment: What is `ga` and where exactly does it come from? Please update your question to include the relevant *imports* - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for comment, as it is mentioned in the second line (also in tags) GA is Genetic Algorithm. I add the import library line to the top of the code for more clarification.

Comment: OK. I did read your question, but "Genetic Algorithm" in general (and in the tags) by no means implies the specific library `geneticalgorithm` (or any other, from the dozen or so out there), about which your question is about...

Comment: The very first thing you are expected to do in such cases (before start searching SO and/or other forums, let alone post a question) is to **check the documentation**! Normally, I would have [downvoted because of no research](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), but alas, I preferred to answer instead (I had never heard of this library before, and the only thing I did is to, well, *read the documentation*...)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the `geneticalgorithm` library [Github page](https://github.com/rmsolgi/geneticalgorithm#function-timeout):

> #### Function timeout
>
> geneticalgorithm is designed such that if the given function does not
> provide any output before timeout (the default value is 10 seconds),
> the algorithm would be terminated and raise the appropriate error. In
> such a case make sure the given function works correctly (i.e. there
> is no infinite loop in the given function). Also if the given function
> takes more than 10 seconds to complete the work make sure to increase
> function_timeout in arguments.

From the [Arguments section](https://github.com/rmsolgi/geneticalgorithm#arguments):

> @param function_timeout - if the given function does not provide
> output before function_timeout (unit is seconds) the algorithm raise
> error. For example, when there is an infinite loop in the given
> function.

So, if you want a time out of, say, 20 sec, you should change your `ga` function to:

```
ga_model = ga(function=loss_fn,
          dimension=(2),
          variable_type='real',
          variable_boundaries=varbound,
          algorithm_parameters=algorithm_param,
          function_timeout = 20)   # <- added
```

Comment: Because in the error it was written "func_timeout," I tried to include this parameter in the model but received an error. But now I see the "function_timeout" is the right word. Thanks again.